# How to post new Facebook status via email?

Tags: facebook, email

A [Google search](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-20103506-285/update-facebook-status-via-e-mail/) on this topic lead me to some instructions that don't work for me - since all `http://www.facebook.com/mobile/` are redirected to `Facebook Home` site.

How can I do it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this up easily on [IFTTT.com](http://ifttt.com) (If This Then That).

You can use email (with or without hashtags etc.) as a trigger to post a status update to facebook. This recipe, [Post to facebook from mail](https://ifttt.com/recipes/13137) uses email to post a status update.

Answer (score 1):

For modern browsers and smartphones Facebook prefers that you upload directly or using an App than post-by-email. So, if you use a modern browser FB will hide the address from you.

You either need to use an old browser or user agent switcher and then the instructions will work.
See http://www.devineprojects.org/blog/archives/2013/07/updated-how-to-find-your-facebook-post-by-email-address-and-post-from-google/ and http://hackingbuzz.com/update-facebook-status-via-email/

Answer (score 1):

The feature appears to be "phased out" and "dropped from the faq".  Refer to
https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10206665176571297
and
https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=981476835197502

In my experience messages to the "post by email" address have returned a Delivery Status Notification (Failure) after 3 days.

Comment: Your answer would be better if you could quote salient text from those locations.

Comment: Too late, those links are dead now...

Comment: @ale the salient text is quoted: "phased out", "dropped from the faq"